SupabaseVectorStore connection (FastAPI backend on Render) failing with "OperationalError... Network is unreachable"
I have a Python backend for my LlamaIndex application (using FastAPI + Render) that uses "SupabaseVectorStore" to set up the connection with my Supabase DB. It works 100% fine locally on localhost, but when I host it in Render, I suddenly get this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "db.[USER_HERE].supabase.co", port [PORT_NUMBER] failed: Network is unreachable
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

The code where the Supabase DB connection is setup is:
import logging
import os

from llama_index.core.indices import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.vector_stores.pinecone import PineconeVectorStore
from llama_index.vector_stores.supabase import SupabaseVectorStore
from llama_index.core import StorageContext

logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")


def get_index():
    logger.info("Connecting to index from Supabase...")
    vector_store = SupabaseVectorStore(
        postgres_connection_string=f"postgresql://{os.environ['SUPABASE_DB_URL']}",
        collection_name="daily_notes",
    )
    storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
    index = VectorStoreIndex(nodes=[], storage_context=storage_context)

    logger.info("Finished connecting to index from Supabase.")
    return index

where:
SUPABASE_DB_URL = postgresql://postgres:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@db.[USER].supabase.co:[PORT]/postgres


UPDATE:
Since reading this post from Supabase, I also tried the "pooling string", where (in addition to updating the code to start with "postgres://"):
SUPABASE_DB_URL = postgres://postgres.[USER]:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@aws-0-us-west-1.pooler.supabase.com:[PORT]/postgres

But this now yields:

sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin:
sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I've been grappling with this for HOURS and am completely lost... 

Note that as LLamaIndex users SQLAlchemy to connect to Supabase's PostgreSQL database, you should use postgresql:// instead of postgres:// as your dialect.

I agree with @Venomouse
Best practice for DevOps is "careful copypasting",
you should get that SUPABASE_DB_URL from your projects dashboard:
https://supabase.com/dashboard/project/qtgzbaejdmqqpprcrvdl/settings/database
For storing secrets locally you can use a .env (do .gitignore)
and set the secret there SUPABASE_DB_URL=
and then in Python you can
load_dotenv()
ENV = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_DB_URL")

